# Change Main Display via Keyboard Shortcut or command line in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, multiple-monitors, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using OS X 10.11.3 (15D21) with one monitor and one projector.

Mirroring is turned off.

Mac OS X has an option to switch the main display (the display that has the upper menu) via the System Preferences, as depicted in the attached screenshot:[image: attached screenshot]

Basically to switch one drags the little menu bar from one side to the other.

My question is: Is there a way to accomplish this switch via the keyboard or better yet as a command from the Terminal?

Comment: What is your goal? To have the dock on both screens?

Comment: My goal is to switch the "main" display (the one that has all the windows I've been working with).

Comment: What you want is to keybind that. look in the keyboard settings and under hotkeys select the display management app and  set a keybinding to it and save.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[hmscreens](https://github.com/mikeakers/hmscreens) work great. Here's a sample command line to swap monitors:

```
hmscreens -setMainID `hmscreens -info | grep "Screen ID:" | head -2 | tail -1 | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'`
```

Comment: The link does not seem to work. Redirects to the home page of that site's domain

Answer (score 4):

The free terminal tool I wrote, [displayplacer](https://github.com/jakehilborn/displayplacer), allows you to configure the main display via scripts/hotkeys.

Configure your screens how you like, drag the "white bar" to your primary screen in the macOS system settings, and then execute `displayplacer list`. It will output the command to run to put your screens in their current configuration. The screen with `origin:(0,0)` is the main display with the "white bar". Run this terminal command through a script or bind to a hotkey using Automator/BetterTouchTool/etc.

This example makes the left screen the primary monitor. Execute a similar command whenever your machine randomly chooses the wrong primary display.
`displayplacer "id:<leftScreenId> res:1920x1080 scaling:on origin:(0,0) degree:0" "id:<rightScreenId> res:1920x1080 scaling:on origin:(1920,0) degree:0"`

Also available via Homebrew `brew tap jakehilborn/jakehilborn && brew install displayplacer`

Comment: While your program may solve the OP’s problem, we prefer answers that explain ***how*** a piece of software can be used to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: @Scott I updated my answer to address your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I, too, am looking for a quick keyboard shortcut to switch display 1 on left to display 2 on right. My clamshell is closed. I accidentally found it when I was actually looking to lock my screen and forgot the shortcut and hit something that swapped my displays to the other.

I think it might have been a left side key combination that either involved the letter S or the letter W, that I hit by accident when I went to hit the letter Q to lock the screen. I've tried several combos without luck.

I am spending more time looking for that shortcut than it would take to symply go into Display prefs, but it would be nice to know it. So be it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).